# How to create landscape image from 2D map?

Tags: algorithm, maps

I created a 2D map using Perlin Noise. Based on the value on x,y, I determine an altitude and so a color to apply to my map (8 levels map).

Now, I don't want my player to see the map but I would like him to show him what he sees when he look North direction.

I'll explain the approaches I used to solve my problem and show you the results, then I'll ask my questions for some whom can help.

**V1 - the pov approach**

I tried a simple approach for the beginning. Based on my character, I start to add what I see in front of me and if I see something higher, i add it on top of the first thing I see + I increase my angle of view.

[image: a pov approach example]

**V2 - the layer approach**

For my second approach, I started far from my player position and started to build layers from far to near him. This way I created a vertical cut (from east to west) and put it flat.

[image: a layer approach example]

**V3 - the layer shadowed approach**

My third approach is based on the second one + I detected that two elements are one far from the other and I took it in count to generate "shadows" (darker borders).

**V4 - the layer shadowed approach + adding pov alteration**

[image]

Based on V3 approch, hard to explain, the near I am, the less the view is important. (reducing the map view).

**Results**

[image: the result rendered]

- I like the way it evolved but I don't like some stuff (for example the cut mountain on first frame)
- The second thing I didn't take in count is the altitude of my character.

Do you have any algorithms to solve this problem? I'm not looking for now for optimizations, just to get the best render. I also posted this article on reddit in /r/algorithms

Comment: See [Realtime Voxel Landscape Engines](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Realtime_Voxel_Landscape_Engines-Part_1_Introduction.shtml) by by Alex Champandard. In particular [part 2](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Realtime_Voxel_Landscape_Engines-Part_2_Rendering_the_Landscapes_Structure.shtml).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't create a vertex grid, displace them based on the altitude, and actually render 3D geometry?

Comment: @Theraot I'll try to check it today and see if it gives me expected results.

Comment: @Peethor I'm not a game developer that's why I didn't search this way, and all you see is rendered using PHP GD. I didn't though about rendering 3D Geometry with GD library, and I don't think GD can handle it. Plus, It's an online game that will not have only one map and I have to render it on the fly.

Comment: This looks similar to ray-marching a heightfield. You might want to read up on parallax occlusion mapping, which uses effectively this technique to render a flat texture as though it had depth. When you see walls in a game with absurdly detailed bricks or cobbles, it's usually this technique running on a flat quad. ;)